Help me show that $\max_{k \leq n}|X_k|$ is a martingale
Related to this question
Setup
$(\Omega, F, P)$; probability space
Let $\{F_n\}_{n=0,1,2,\ldots}$ be a filtration, and $X=\{X_n\}_{n=0,1,2,\ldots}$ be an adapted process.
In addition, we define
$$
X^\ast_n = \max_{k\leq n}|X_k|.
$$
Then, $X^\ast=\{X^\ast_n\}_{n=0,1,2,\ldots}$ is adapted.
In addition, we want to show that $X^\ast$ is a martingale.
My try
It is sufficient to show that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^\ast_{n+1}\mid F_n] = X^\ast_n.
$$
I have not been able to deal with $\max$ well, but I think we can generally indicate this policy:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^\ast_{n+1}\mid F_n] = \mathbb{E}[\max_{k\leq n+1}|X_k|\mid F_n] = \ldots = \max_{k\leq n}|X_k| = X^\ast_n
$$
I am stuck because I cannot transform it properly.

An increasing process cannot be martingale (unless it is a constant). Where did you get this question from?

@geetha290krm I asked the question without any confirmation that it was martingale. It could also be a sub-martingale.

Exercise: show that $X^*_n$ it is always a submartingale.

If $X_n=n$ with probability one, then $X_n^\ast=n$ and $\mathbb E[X^\ast_{n+1}|F_n]=n+1\neq n= X_n^\ast$. Since you have $X^\ast_{n+1}\geq X^\ast_n$, you get that $X^\ast_n$ is a submartingale.
Note that your process is a Martingale if and only if the initial $X_n$ is almost surely non increasing, i.e. $\mathbb P[X_{n+1} > X_n]=0$ for all $n$.

Why can we assume $X_n=n$?

$n$ is a constant and is therefore measurable with any $F_n$, it is therefore an adapted process and satisfies all your conditions.
